# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token =" in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, class

I was working with a NodeJS project and I got an error after declaring a class.

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const { EventEmitter } = require("events");

class DbConnection extends EventEmitter{

  mongoClient = new MongoClient(
    "mongodb+srv://xxxx:xxxx@xxxx.xxxx.mongodb.net/xxxx?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
  );

  getConnection(){
    this.mongoClient.connect((err, mongodb) => {
      console.log(mongoClient);
      if (err) throw err;
      this.emit("dbConnection", {
        db: this.mongoClient.db("passport")
      });
      DbConnection.setInstance(mongodb);
    });
  }

  static setInstance(mongodb){
    DbConnection.db = mongodb.db("passport");
    DbConnection.userCollection = DbConnection.db.collection("user");
  }

}

module.exports = DbConnection;
```

The error is at line 6 of this file (*mongoClient = new MongoClient*). The error is:

```
  mongoClient = new MongoClient(
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

I don't understand the reason considering that in another project I used the same code and it works.
Any solution? Tnx

Comment: you need to check node version, as there some restrictions in es6 class syntax. Upgrade to > 12.x.x and it should work

Comment: I was just asking for an help not an unfriendly question

Comment: Oh thanks, i had Node to 10.19.0

Answer (score 0):

Use mongoose instead

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const { dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, dbname, dbport } = process.env;
    let connection_url = `mongodb://${dbuser}:${encodeURIComponent(dbpass)}@${dbhost}:${dbport}/${dbname}`

    mongoose
    .connect(connection_url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true 
  })
    .then(async () => {
        winston.info(`Connected to ${connection_url} ...`);

        mongoose.set('debug', true);

        resolve();
    }).catch(reject);
})
```

It is worked for me.